# How can I install Kobold2D reference in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

As the title says, how can I install Kobold2D reference in my Xcode help?

The reference is here:

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/2.0/Kobold2D-mac/html/index.html

Added screenshot from another user for clarification:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply by installing [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Kobold2D+Download). The installer will copy the .docset files in the appropriate directory. Which is: `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets`

You may have to close and re-open the Xcode Organizer window for the docsets to show up in the help section.

**Note:** the Kobold2D files from my [Learn Cocos2D book's page](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/) don't include the Xcode docsets for download size reasons. But you can safely download and install Kobold2D and then continue working with the book's projects, they won't be affected by installing Kobold2D.

Comment: I have installed Kobold2D and there is files like com.kobold2d.kobold2d-mac.docset in my /DocSets directory, but there isn't documentation in Xcode's help.

Comment: I have the same problem. The docsets with the kobold2d api are in the right place but don't appear in Xcode. All the other apis like kobold2d.cocos2d are shown.

Comment: No change with the newest version 2.1.0, the documentation is simply not available in the organizer

Comment: perhaps a permission issue

Comment: No, I have read & write permissions like all the other docsets. Dash works with the kobold2d documentation. But Xcode doesn't :(, any other idea?

Comment: I could easily create a DocSet with AppleDocs, from my own files. Doxygen could have problems with that, maybe you should consider a change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a workaround. I used the DocSet downloaded from Dash.

With a fresh install of Xcode 4.6 and Kobold2D 2.1.0 the only DocSet not showing up in Xcode was that of Kobold2D. The Kobold2D installation copied all the DocSets to the right folder, but Xcode was not able to detect it.

Even Dash can't import some of the DocSets installed with Kobold2D 2.1.0
Here is a screenshot when I try to add the DocSet not showing up in Xcode:

[image]

Not working DocSets from Kobold2D 2.1.0 installation are:

- Chipmunk Spacemanager
- Cocos2D iPhone Extensions
- Cocos2D iPhone Extensions Mac
- Cocos3D
- Cocos Denshion Mac
- Cocos Denshion
- Kobold2D Mac
- Kobold2D
- Sneaky Input

---

Here step-by-step what I did to get it:

Kobold2D 2.1.0 in Xcode 4.6
Download Kobold2D Documentation in Dash
In the Preferences of Dash, the app is available free in the AppStore. You don't need to keep it.
[image]

Then find the file downloaded.

[image]

Then copy from the Dash folder to the DocSets folder of Xcode:
~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/

[image]

Restart Xcode if it is running and Tadaa the DocSet of Kobold2D shows up in Xcode.

[image]